# Javascript - onchange event handler function argument not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.css" media="screen, projection">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function loadOperators(rowID)
{
    alert("ROW: " + rowID);
}

var lastRowID = 1;

// Add new row
$('input#addrow').live('click', function(){

    lastRowID += 1;

    var $clonedRow = $('tr#row_1').clone();

    // manipulating new ids for the elements in the newly created row
    $clonedRow.find('*').andSelf().filter('[id]').each(function() {
        var string = this.id;

        pos = string.lastIndexOf('_');

        var tempStr = string.substr(0, pos);

        this.id = tempStr + "_" + lastRowID;
    });

    $clonedRow.insertBefore("#clone_table tr#spacer_row");

    $("#field_id_" + lastRowID).on('change', function(){
        loadOperators(lastRowID);
    });

});



// Delete a row
$('input#delrow').live('click', function(){

    if(lastRowID == 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    $('tr#row_' + lastRowID).remove();

    lastRowID -= 1;
});



$(document).ready(function() {

    loadOperators(lastRowID);

    $("#field_id_1").on('change', function(){
        loadOperators(lastRowID);
    });
});

//-->
</script>

</head>

<body>

<table id="clone_table" width="700" cellpadding="0" border="0">

<colgroup>
    <col width="200">
    <col width="200">
    <col width="200">
</colgroup>

<tr id="row_1">
    <td>
        <select name="field_id_1" id="field_id_1">
            <option value="1">Item One</option>
            <option value="2">Item Two</option>
            <option value="3">Item Three</option>       
        </select>
    </td>

    <td id="operator_strip_1"></td>

    <td id="">&#160;</td>   
</tr>

<tr id="spacer_row"><td colspan="3">&#160;</td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="3">&#160;</td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="3"><input type="button" id="addrow" value="More" /> <input type="button" id="delrow" value="Less" /></td></tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to add and delete rows to a HTML table dynamically.
But the generated row contains one combo box with a **onchange** event handler function.
I need to pass the row ID to that function. When I assign the new ID to the latest combo box's **onchange** event handler, it is changing the value assigned to the already generated combo boxes also. Can anyone look this code and tell me what is causing the issue here?

Comment: .live is deprecated; just use .on instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reference `lastRowID` in the call to `loadOperators`, you're getting the current value, because the variable is not local to the `click` handler function. You don't need the variable, you can just use `this.id`.

```
$('input#addrow').live('click', function(){

    lastRowID += 1;

    var $clonedRow = $('tr#row_1').clone();

    // manipulating new ids for the elements in the newly created row
    $clonedRow.find('*').andSelf().filter('[id]').each(function() {
        var string = this.id;

        pos = string.lastIndexOf('_');

        var tempStr = string.substr(0, pos);

        this.id = tempStr + "_" + lastRowID;
    });

    $clonedRow.insertBefore("#clone_table tr#spacer_row");

    $("#field_id_" + lastRowID).on('change', function(){
        loadOperators(this.id);
    });

});
```

Instead of binding a handler every time you add a row, you could use delegation. Give all the `field_id_N` elements a class (`field_class` in the example below), and do this just once in the document.ready function:

```
$("#clone_table").on('change', '.field_class', function() {
    loadOperators(this.id);
});
```

I'm not sure what the real `loadOperators()` function does (the one in your question is obviously just a stub), but I suspect you could just pass `this` to it instead of the ID, and you could probably get rid of all IDs in the elements that get cloned.

If you really need the `lastRowID` value, you can copy it into a local variable, which will be captured in the closure.

```
$('input#addrow').live('click', function(){

    lastRowID += 1;
    var thisRowID = lastRowID;

    var $clonedRow = $('tr#row_1').clone();

    // manipulating new ids for the elements in the newly created row
    $clonedRow.find('*').andSelf().filter('[id]').each(function() {
        var string = this.id;

        pos = string.lastIndexOf('_');

        var tempStr = string.substr(0, pos);

        this.id = tempStr + "_" + lastRowID;
    });

    $clonedRow.insertBefore("#clone_table tr#spacer_row");

    $("#field_id_" + lastRowID).on('change', function(){
        loadOperators(thisRowID);
    });

});
```

Comment: 'loadOperators' needs the argument value: 1, 2, 3,.. etc. for each combo box instead of 'this.id'. I did not understand the problem of global variable 'lastRowID'. Whenever I add a new combo box(ie, on each Add button click), I am using the current value of 'lastRowID' to set the value to the new combo box's 'loadOperators' function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there any other way around for using the `lastRowID` instead of `this.id`?